# Is there a tool that allows to edit related code in single file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, editing

My idea is that it's much easier to edit related code when it sits in single "work" file. E.g. in Rails application when you implementing some functionality you may edit 1 function per file in the following files: integration test, controller test, controller, model, controller helper. So if it would be possible to 1) mark this code fragments 2) automatically collect them in "work" file 3) edit them togather 4) the tool synchronizes (puts back) the changes; it could simplify development process in many cases. Especially if you need to go through many tweek-and-try iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Vim works fine for this. Install the Rails.vim(1) plugin and with the command :AV you can open a vertical split with the accompanied tests/specs, or :RV to open related files like migrations and views (depending on whether you're viewing model or controller). When you're workspace becomes to cluttered, use :only to go back to one file. Splits are the best way to manage multiple related files IMHO. You can even open the same file twice to see two parts of the same file. It's not exactly the same as you are describing, but it comes close.

1: http://rails.vim.tpope.net/

Answer (score 0):

Just open up Vim and open some windows. What's the problem?

Comment: 1. I prefer Rubymine :) 2. I want to see the whole set of related code (I'm not sure if you can do that in non-awkward way with multiple windows) 3. eventually you will open many quite unrelated files, that "trash" your set of opened files